# How do I move the OneDrive folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have a tablet with a tiny amount of file space left on the main drive (`C:`). I'd live to move my OneDrive folder to the SD card, but I can find no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was go into the disk management utility, remove my sd card as a drive letter, and then mount it in an NTFS folder.

From what I've read, Microsoft stopped letting people move it to external drives, but mounting it to an internal drive's directory worked.